# What is the state-of-the-art non-parametric PDF estimation?

Tags: self-study, kernel-smoothing, density-estimation

Below is some data points that are generated by a process that is normally distributed with $\mu=5$ and $\sigma=0.5$. But of course, we will pretend that we don't know the true distribution of the process as the PDF estimation below is supposed to be non-parametric.

What I am doing here is:

- Finding CDF empirically (thus non-parametric).
- For missing regions on the CDF, I linearly interpolate.
- Then I differentiate the linearly interpolated CDF to get a PDF. Since the CDF is the result of linear interpolation, the PDF at any point is merely the slope of a line.

Here is what I get for $10$ data points (generator code is in the Python code below, but I paste it here for convenience):

```
[5.470857702340332,
4.3017109476494255,
4.660142775960789,
5.18525178373033,
4.491825552905965,
4.963939988607464,
5.089598243637428,
4.584450392364506,
4.345481317770321,
5.0969438706245525]
```

[image]

Here is the same but for $500$ data points (too many data points to paste here, but you can generate it from the code below; it's in variable S):
[image]

It is very clear from the empirical CDF that it's the CDF of a normal distribution. But the PDF looks really bad in my view.

I think it boils down to finding "optimum" smoothing function. So I think the question is "what is the state-of-the art smoothing function"?

Below is my code (in case it helps):

```py
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# function that gives you pdf at point x
def get_pdf(x,cdf_x,cdf_y):
    x_before = -1
    y_before = -1
    x_after  = -1
    y_after  = -1
    for i in range(0,len(cdf_x)):
        if x > cdf_x[i]:
            x_before = cdf_x[i]
            y_before = cdf_y[i]
        else:
            x_after = cdf_x[i]
            y_after = cdf_y[i]
            break
    if x_before == -1 or x_after == -1:
        slope = 0
    else:
        slope = abs(y_before - y_after) / float(abs(x_before - x_after))
    return slope


def test():
    random.seed(0)
    # let's generate n normally distributed samples
    n = 500
    mu = 5
    sigma = 0.5
    S = [random.gauss(mu, sigma) for i in range(n)]

    # let's find CDF
    cdf_p = dict() # cdf key points
    for x in S:
        n_lt_x = 0
        for s in S:
            if s <= x:
                n_lt_x += 1
        cdf_p[x] = n_lt_x / float(n)
    cdf_x = cdf_p.keys() # x axis of the CDF
    cdf_x.sort()
    cdf_y = [cdf_p[i] for i in cdf_x]

    # find PDF by differentiating a linearly interpolated PDF
    pdf_x = []
    pdf_y = []
    pdf_y_anal = []
    for x in np.arange(min(cdf_x)-1,max(cdf_x)+1, 0.01):
        pdf_x.append(x)
        pdf_y.append(get_pdf(x,cdf_x,cdf_y))
        pdf_y_anal.append(1/(sigma*np.sqrt(2*np.pi)) * np.power(np.e, -np.power(x-mu,2)/(2*np.power(sigma,2))))

    # plot
    plt.plot(cdf_x, cdf_y, 'bo-', label='CDF')
    plt.plot(pdf_x, pdf_y, 'ro-', label='estimated PDF')
    plt.plot(pdf_x, pdf_y_anal, 'b--', label='true PDF', linewidth=3)
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

Here is another figure but while binning the CDF:
[image]

And here is its code:

```py
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# function that gives you pdf at point x
def get_pdf(x,cdf_x,cdf_y):
    x_before = -1
    y_before = -1
    x_after  = -1
    y_after  = -1
    for i in range(0,len(cdf_x)):
        if x > cdf_x[i]:
            x_before = cdf_x[i]
            y_before = cdf_y[i]
        else:
            x_after = cdf_x[i]
            y_after = cdf_y[i]
            break
    if x_before == -1 or x_after == -1:
        slope = 0
    else:
        slope = abs(y_before - y_after) / float(abs(x_before - x_after))
    return slope


def test():
    random.seed(0)
    # let's generate n normally distributed samples
    n = 500
    mu = 5
    sigma = 0.5
    S = [random.gauss(mu, sigma) for i in range(n)]

    # let's find CDF
    cdf_p = dict() # cdf key points
    for x in np.arange(0,max(S),0.5):
        n_lt_x = 0
        for s in S:
            if s <= x:
                n_lt_x += 1
        cdf_p[x] = n_lt_x / float(n)
    cdf_x = cdf_p.keys() # x axis of the CDF
    cdf_x.sort()
    cdf_y = [cdf_p[i] for i in cdf_x]

    # find PDF by differentiating a linearly interpolated PDF
    pdf_x = []
    pdf_y = []
    pdf_y_anal = []
    for x in np.arange(min(cdf_x)-1,max(cdf_x)+1, 0.01):
        pdf_x.append(x)
        pdf_y.append(get_pdf(x,cdf_x,cdf_y))
        pdf_y_anal.append(1/(sigma*np.sqrt(2*np.pi)) * np.power(np.e, -np.power(x-mu,2)/(2*np.power(sigma,2))))

    # plot
    plt.plot(cdf_x, cdf_y, 'bo-', label='CDF')
    plt.plot(pdf_x, pdf_y, 'ro-', label='estimated PDF')
    plt.plot(pdf_x, pdf_y_anal, 'b--', label='true PDF', linewidth=3)
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: You seem to be spending most of your post [asking about an attempted solution to a problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/202463) rather than focusing on the original problem (which the title would imply you actually care about). There are common approaches that would typically seem to do better than what you're showing here, including kernel density estimates and logspline density estimates (among others). They may not be "state of the art", which tends to be more adapted to specific aspects of problems (e.g. solving the problem under particular conditions) than generic solutions.

Comment: Could you post your 10 data points? It might be useful for people discussing alternative approaches

Comment: @Glen_b thank you. I added the 10 data points. As for the format, I added my attempted solution because this also has the self-study tag (which I think including attempted solutions is required for self-study). Most of the question is the attempted study because the question is simple to state (didn't take me long)

Comment: Ah, sorry I missed that. Yes, it's fair enough in that case.

Comment: The 10 points you posted aren't the 10 points in your picture.

Comment: Sorry, now it's the correct one (had to regenerate it with random.seed(0))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the noisiness of your original solution is in large part because you're dividing by differences in order statistics. When they're close together (as will often be the case), this makes your pdf estimate "jump" up very high, which would lead to the high level of noise.

There are common approaches for nonparametric density estimation.

Perhaps the most common "good" one is [kernel density estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) which is well described in numerous texts as well as [many posts on site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kernel-smoothing). A much older one is of course the histogram. There's also log-spline density estimation and a number of other approaches. Usually I just stick with vanilla kde unless there's something special about the problem (like a bounded variable or a density on a circle).

Kernel density estimation essentially replaces data points of weight 1/n (i.e. a discrete distribution at the observed values) with densities ("kernels") scaled to area 1/n centered at the data points, which have spread related to a parameter called the bandwidth, producing an $n$-component [mixture density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution#Finite_and_countable_mixtures) of the kernels centered at each data value with $w_i=\frac{1}{n}$

In the end I digitized your data myself:

```
4.302 4.347 4.494 4.589 4.664 4.966 5.091 5.098 5.189 5.472
```

So here's an example at three bandwidths:

[image]

One bandwidth is close to the default (data-determined) value in R and the other two are double and half that respectively.

Here the kernel is Gaussian (again, the default in R).

I've added one for a (different) random set of data with n=500 (but generated from the same distribution as yours), this time using the Sheather-Jones bandwidth (solid line -- which works pretty well across a range of circumstances):

[image: ![enter image description here]

As you see it does a pretty good job of recovering the density (dotted line).

Comment: Interesting, very helpful. I got a bit lost when reading your description about KDE. Can you say whether this perfectly correct: KDE aims to estimate density at input point $x$, namely $f_X(x)$, and it does so by looking at all $x_i$ that fall within $h$ distance from $x$, then -instead of counting each such $x_i$ as 1- it weights the count of each $x_i$ by some weight $w_i$, and this weight is determined by the chosen kernel that is centred on $x_i$. Is this perfect? Also, can I say that all KDE methods only differ by their selection of such tiny kernels per $x_i$?

Comment: @caveman It contains some errors. For kernels on a nonbounded interval (like the Gaussian) every point has some impact on the estimate at some particular $x$. For *some* kinds of kernel the bandwidth can be a hard bound how far away it looks, but for others it isn't. KDE methods can differ in a number of ways - kernel choice, method of bandwidth choice, whether (and how) the bandwidth can vary, and so on. (Note that there are a few basic explanations of KDEs on site; some may help. But it's a topic that fills books)

Comment: Thank you very much. I wonder how is this related to Kernel Regression? I am very fuzzy on this, but my attempt is this: Kernel regression tries to 1st perform KDE and generate many density points, and then run a regression algorithm to fit a smooth curve across those densities. So in a sense to me it seems a 2-stage density estimation that begins by KDE and ends by regression.

Comment: Nope. The use of the kernel in [kernel regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_regression) defines the weight in a locally-weighted average of the $y$s -- nearer points to $x$ get more weight